# Exclude uncategorized posts from search and archive pages

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress site I want to prevent any uncategorized posts from showing up in site searches and in archive pages - including the front page of recent posts.

The only places that I want uncategorised posts to be visible are the actual posts themselves, and on the author archive pages, eg example.com/author/authorName

I have looked in vain for a plugin. I reckon there must be some custom php, but my skills are not that deep.

Any help or clues greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You have to exclude the category from the loop in your `archive.php` and `index.php`. This example uses category ID numbers, which you can find by going to **Posts >> Categories**. You'll see the ID for each category.

In your files mentioned above, find the loop

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-1' ); ?> // This is where you exclude. You can comma separate multiple categories : 'cat=-1,-2,-3' etc
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

 <div class="post">

 <!-- Here is the post content - use whatever your theme is using -->

 </div> 

 <?php endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
 else : ?>
 <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

As for the search results, try this. This will go in `functions.php` (I haven't tested it so let me know if there are issues).

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'search_exclude' );
function search_exclude( $query ) {

if( $query->is_admin )
return $query;

if( $query->is_search ) {
$query->set( 'category__not_in' , array( 1 ) ); // Category ID
}
return $query;
}
```

Please note: you can also comma separate the categories here by doing this:

```
$query->set( 'category__not_in' , array( 1,2,3 ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, this is really excellent. After more digging I actually did find a plugin that works - called Advanced Category Excluder, but your solution is much more elegant and so I will give it a go and let you know how it goes, thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, I could not get the code modification to work - I guess the theme I am using is a bit different, eg does not have archive.php file, but you have inspired me to learn more about php - thanks again!

Comment: No I got errors. Here's the loop code in index.php:

Comment: `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  
   <!-- loops-wrapper -->
   <div id="loops-wrapper" class="loops-wrapper <?php echo $themify->layout . ' ' . $themify->post_layout; ?>">

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  
     <?php if(is_search()): ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'includes/loop' , 'search'); ?>
     <?php else: ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'includes/loop' , 'index'); ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
  
    <?php endwhile; ?>
       
   </div>
   <!-- /loops-wrapper -->

   <?php get_template_part( 'includes/pagination'); ?>`